ALTIUM SPICE Simulation: MOSFET switching power
I am trying to simulate a switching MOSFET circuit in Altium, and I'd like to get a energy measured during the conmutation. So far, I could simulate it properly, but I can't find the integral operation to get the energy (area under the curve) during the conmutation. I think in the previous versions of Altium (AD22) there was a function called INT that actually did what I want, but I can't find that in AD24 :(
Here is the link where I found it >> https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/working-with-generated-analysis-waveforms?version=22
Also, this is the simulation result I want to calculate the energy dissipated:
Thank you in advance for the help!! ;)

I am not familiar with Altium as a simulator, I use SiMetrix and LTspice.  In both of those simulators, you can build your own integrator: simply create a dependant current source that generates a current with the variable you want to integrate, then connect that across a capacitor.   The voltage across that capacitor is in the integral.

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Scroll down to Editing Waveforms - Getting Mathematical: you can edit the waveform and write an expression there.  This is (mostly) equivalent to the postprocessor that most SPICE tools have.  In this case, you'll need something like int(V(VDS,0)*L1[i]) -- or, whatever the nodes/elements are that you're measuring.
You can also construct an integrator on the schematic, easily enough; using the Simulation Function library, for example.
Waveform edits are very limited in other analysis modes, unfortunately, but it's reasonably handy for transient.
